# Retroactive benefits cut

Tags: united-states, iowa

My company just announced that they will no longer award paid time off, effective 15 days before the announcement. I’m concerned that such a change may not be legal.

I am paid monthly. My job is at-will. My offer specified a certain wage and certain benefits, including X paid days off per month which may accumulate to a certain limit and Y paid sick days per month which may accumulate without limit. Upon separation, my unused paid time off is paid out to me and sick leave is forfeited. The retroactive application date is the start of the current pay period.

I haven’t used the time off that is being retroactively removed. (I couldn’t without special permission, in the same way that I couldn’t spend the pay period’s wages until they are paid into my bank account.)
I understand that no law requires granting paid time off (with a few exceptions).

Intuitively, it seems like it would be illegal for a company to say they decided to pay only 50% of the promised wages for time already worked. But I’m not sure whether the same intuition applies to paid time off awards.

Is it legal for a company to retroactively reduce or eliminate non-wage compensation for time already worked?

Comment: If you got "paid time off", then you didn't work those hours, you'd be getting free money. There are some details about what the worker did / didn't do, and what exact promise was made that you think was broken. How exactly is this "getting 50% of promised wages"? Did the worker make some choice to not work when they had the option to work, based on a "free money" promise?

Comment: @user6726 Its not "free money" if it's a benefit - it's part of your reimbursement package.  Calling it "free money" adds a negative label to it - its paid holiday.  Standard across most of the world except for the US it would seem.  If its an accepted part of your reimbursement, and you took advantage of it and it was removed from you after you took advantage of it but before you receive the payment, then there is most likely an actionable issue here.

Comment: Four weeks of paid leave is equivalent to about 8% of the annual income. At least one jurisdiction requires paying this additional 8% if the employee is not otherwise entitled to an annual leave balance. It's a massive paycut to have paid leave suddenly taken away, and should be treated as such. @user6726

Comment: Insofar as the question is tagged with Iowa, it's safe to assume US legal standards. It's not safe to assume that this is part of a contractual package – the OP can clarify the facts.

Comment: @user6726 the *contractual* aspect won't matter if the op relied on the benefit and was allowed to rely on the benefit - you almost certainly can't have a benefit which you remove after its been taken advantage of and leave the employee out of pocket, when you allowed the employee to take advantage in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I’ve updated the question. I haven’t used the time off and couldn’t because it isn’t added to my available balance until the end of the month. I worked under the understanding that I would be compensated, in both money and available paid time off. (But perhaps my understanding is flawed—hence this question.)